# How can I tell Hibernate Validator to throw exception if the incoming request has less or extra fields than the POJO

Tags: java, hibernate, bean-validation, hibernate-validator

For example my POJO has two field

```
public class User {
    @NotNull
    private String firstName;
    @NotNull
    private String lastName;
}
```

if the incoming request body is like the following, the hibernate won't throw any error, since all required field is there.

```
{
  "firstName": "cat",
  "lastName": "dog",
  "extraField": "whatever"
}
```

Is there any way I can tell hibernate to check this kind of scenario? I know I can just `@JsonCreator` to do the trick. But is it the good approach to combine both hibernate and Jackson together?

Comment: This validation must happen before it reaches hibernate. What is your web stack?

Comment: @aksappy I am just using a spring boot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using auto configuration then the following property in application.properties will do the trick.

```
spring.jackson.deserialization.fail-on-unknown-properties=true
```

This is equivalent to the following

```
objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, true);
```

I did a small test without spring and it throws an exception `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException`